# Application.ScreenUpdating toggle

Tags: excel, vba, toggle

I'm looking for the simplest way to toggle ScreenUpdating via call.
Can you please advise if this solution could have any adverse effects?

```
Sub Toggle_Screen_Updating()
With Application
   .ScreenUpdating = IIf(.ScreenUpdating, False, True)
End with
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will toggle it.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = Not Application.ScreenUpdating
```

I recommend not to use toggleing because you never clearly know the state after running this line. You only know that is is the opposite that it was before.

I recommend to explicitly run `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` whenever you want to turn it off and `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` whenever you want to turn it on.

I see no advantage in using a toggle instead.

Comment: Thank you PEH, this does not only answer my question but also provides valuable advice for coding good practice!